# subsructing getchar's return value

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a file which is consists of a single string

```
a1
```

If I write this:

```
char ch = getchar();
char ch1 = getchar();
cout << ch - 'a'  << " " << ch1 - '0' << endl;
```

I have `0 1` in output. But if I write this:

```
cout << getchar() - 'a'  << " " << getchar() - '0' << endl;
```

I have `-48 49`.
Doesnt getchar() return a normal char? Why the result isn't the same?

Comment: Not directly relevant to your question, but `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`. This is so that the value `EOF` can be guaranteed to be distinct from any valid input character.

Comment: @KeithThompson , yes, thanks you. I didnt know this. but `cout << (char)getchar() - 'a' << " " << (char)getchar() - '0' << endl;` doesnt work too

Comment: @Angew: You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Dima: Right. Note that the subtraction is irrelevant; `cout << getchar() << " " << getchar() << endl;` shows the same problem.

Comment: @Angew what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the issue because the two calls to `getchar()` are evaluated in unspecified order, and your compiler happens to evaluate the rightmost one first.

C++ has rather loose rules regarding order of evaluation of subexpressions in an expression, to allow for more optimisation opportunities. The `cout` line is one expression, where the following is guaranteed:

- the first `getchar()` will be evaluated before the first `-`
- the second `getchar()` will be evaluated before the second `-`
- the first `-` will be evaluated before the first `<<`
- the second `-` will be evaluated before the third `<<`
- the `<<`s will be evaluated in order from the left.

Note that there are no other ordering restrictions. For example, the compiler is free to evaluate both `getchar()` calls and both `-`s before the first `<<`. Most importantly, there is no rule forcing the first `getchar()` to be evaluated before the second one.

Comment: but they are not equal by abs? `'1' - 'a' == -('a' - '1')` but `48 != -49`

Comment: @Dima I don't follow. Your input says `a1`. Which means the first `getchar()` evaluated reads the `a`, and the second one reads the `1`. You're subtracting `'a'` and `'0'`. So in your case, it comes up as `'1' - 'a'` and `'a' - '0'`.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Im stupind. I changed my file after debugging and was wondering wats going on. Sorry, sir.